# Odd opacity transition with CSS

Tags: css-transitions, opacity

I have a menu which changes the color from white to brown progressively  when the mouse is over. However, when I leave the mouse, the transition begins from white when it should be from brown to white and I don´t know why. When I move the mouse over, the transition is fine. I copy the CSS:

```
li{
letter-spacing: 2px;
margin-bottom: -10px;
max-width: 280px;
opacity: 0.5;
transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
li:hover{
color: #9b2108;
opacity:1;
transition: opacity 3s linear;
}
```

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure on how you mean, but have a look at these changes. Is it what you are looking for?

```
li{
letter-spacing: 2px;
margin-bottom: -10px;
max-width: 280px;
opacity: 0.5;
transition: all 1s linear;
}

li:hover{
color: #9b2108;
opacity:1;
transition: opacity 3s linear, color 3s linear;
}
```

As you can see, I'm transitioning both `opacity` and `color` on hover, and `all` when you hover out. **EDIT:** realized that you can actually change the hover transition to `all` as well.

Or if you want the `color`to take an immediate effect on hover you can leave the hover transition as you had it.

Comment: Exactly Christofer, I went up the seconds of the first transition to make it more usual but that is. Thanks a lot friend.

Comment: My answer got a bit messy, but I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Only the li element needs the transition applied to it.

```
li {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin: 0 0 -10px;
    max-width: 280px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

li:hover {
    color: #9b2108;
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

Comment: The result is the same. This happens when the text has a different color. When I leave the mouse the effect doesn´t work properly, firstly the text appears white with the max opacity and then begins to dissapear due to the transition. I don´t want the next transition:

hover -> white 0.5 to brown 1 -> leave -> white 1 to white 0.5
but
hover -> white 0.5 to brown 1 -> leave -> brown 1 to white 0.5

Thanks.